# Meaning of た form + なら

Tags: conditionals, past

What I've studied is that in Japanese, you don't use past tenses in conditional sentences to express a lower probability (like *if I were* instead of *if I am*). I know there's a conditional formed with た form (たら), but it doesn't have anything to do with probability.

From that, I guessed that if I saw a た form followed by なら, it wouldn't mean less probability but actual past tense. For example:

> もしも僕がミュージシャンだったなら

should mean *if I've been a musician*, rather than *if I were a musician*. But I've heard a lot of these sentences where the actual meaning seems to be the second one.

So in what cases is it correct to use the た form before なら and what exact nuance does it give to the conditional sentence?

(EDIT) Some example sentences:

> もしも僕が名医だったなら、親父の病気は僕が治す。

> もしも僕が王様だったなら、嫌いなやつは全員消えてもらう。

> もしも僕がミュージシャンだったなら、言葉にならない言葉を紡ぐ。

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean about probability. As for your example sentence, you already know whether or not you were a musician; there is no ambiguity. So the only admissible interpretation of なら here would be the counterfactual, i.e. 'if I were a musician ... '. Perhaps you could think of a different example where the ambiguity is clearer.

Comment: @user3856370 Sorry, English is not my native language. But what I mean is that in English you have zero conditional, first conditional, second conditional and third conditional. In Japanese you don't really have this distinction, but もしも, as I understand it, makes it very close to the meaning of the second conditional. What I don't understand is why the verb is in past tense if the sentence is in present tense. So I guessed that た form might also have something to do with probability/ambiguity.

Comment: I think it would he helpful if you would give a full example sentence, where the meaning is unclear to you. In general, there are cases where you wouldn't use the past tense in English, but would in Japanese when using から, because から isn't an exact translation of "if". For example 「彼がきたなら…」 = "When he comes home, ..." .

Comment: Is the sentence really in present tense though? The sentence could be talking about "if they were a musician in the past", and the result of the conditional could be referring to the present/future. I think it would really help if there was more context.

Comment: @Garbaz yeah well it's from a song where there are several conditional sentences and some of them have that pattern. Some examples: 「もしも僕は名医だったなら、親父の病気は僕が治す」, 「もしも僕は王様だったなら、嫌いなやつは全員消えてもらう」or 「もしも僕はミュージシャンだったなら、言葉にならない言葉を紡ぐ」.

Comment: @Shurim well they're not really past or present, more like improbable situations... that I don't really know if fit in a tense. Please check my last comment.

Comment: @Fernando Looking at these sentences, that actually is an interesting question. And I don't think I can give you satisfactory answer without leaning a bit outside what I'm confident about. One thing to note is that なら usually has a connotation that the preceding clause happens after the succeeding clause, which in this case would make no sense of course. By making the first statement in the past tense, this is avoided.

Comment: @Garbaz my only guess is that it may actually be past tense, but only looking at it from the second clause's point of view. Like "if I was a musician, (after having already become a musician) I could do (whatever that sentence says)".

Comment: As for the difference between たら and たなら, [this article might help](https://www.lang.nagoya-u.ac.jp/nichigen/0-kyouiku/research/kotoba/19/12kosaka19.pdf)

Comment: @Shurim I think this is probably what I was looking for. It will take a while for me to translate it but it will be a nice exercise. Thank you so much!

Comment: A clause ends with なら is a subordinate clause. You can't have a topic inside a subordinate clause (except for quotation). Thus you can't use は to mark any argument in the clause that ends with なら. You have to change all は that comes before なら to が in your examples.

Comment: @broccolifacemask-cloth sorry yes, it's が. I'll edit it.