# Why are conflicting verb tenses allowed in usage of なら

Tags: grammar, translation, tense

In https://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n4-grammar-exercise-7/ I encountered the following sentence:

> 父は何でも作れたんだ。
>
> **戸棚が必要なら、父が作ってくれた。**

If I were to translate this into English, I'm guessing it would be

> Father could make anything.
>
> If I **need** a cupboard, father **would have made** it for me.

Notice I internally translated as **need** instead of **needed** because it was 〜が必要なら and not 〜が必要だったなら.

Similarly, I internally translated as **would have made** because of the past form in the phrase 作ってくれた.

Looking at my internal translation, however, I end up getting confused because of the divergence of tenses. Surely, the sentence would have been better translated as:

- If I need a cupboard, father would make it for me.

or

- If I needed a cupboard, father would have made one for me.

In other words, perhaps the sentence could have been:

> 戸棚が必要なら、父が作ってくれるだろう。

In essence, I'm perhaps not understanding how tenses are evaluated. So what did the sentence actually mean? How am I supposed to interpret it correctly?

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to post and answer because the sentence also sounds weird to me, but I want to point out that 戸棚が必要なら is neither past nor present tense, because there is no verb. だったなら doesn't sound right to me. Maybe 必要だったら, is ok, but then,  aren't ~たら (and ~れば) similar to なら as *conditionals*?

Comment: So, I can't definitely say for sure, but if I had to choose I'd say the meaning is the second one: "If I needed a cupboard, father would have made one for me." Same as if the sentence were 戸棚が必要だったら or 戸棚が必要であれば

Comment: @jarmanso7 Although it seems that there are many uses of "だったなら" in internet... Also https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27803/, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82869/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence simply means:

> 戸棚が必要なら、父が作ってくれた。
> When(ever) a cupboard was necessary, Father made it (for me/us).

However, if the context so far clearly indicates the cupboard never existed, the following "counterfactual" or "subjunctive" interpretation is also possible (のに can be used for clarity).

> 戸棚が必要なら、父が作ってくれた(のに)。
> If a cupboard is/was necessary, Father would have made it! (counterfactual)

Related: [How to express the subjunctive mood in Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64544/5010)

---

I think なら is a tense-less expression; it's interchangeable with 必要であるなら or 必要だったなら/必要であったなら depending on the subsequent context.

- 今すぐ必要なら、持って行ってください。
  = 今すぐ必要であるなら、持っていってください。
  If you need it right now, take it.
- 明日必要なら、言ってください。
  = 明日必要であるなら、言ってください。
  If you will need it tomorrow, tell me so.
- その時必要なら、なぜそう言わなかったの？
  = その時必要だったなら、なぜそう言わなかったの？
  If you needed it at that time, why didn't you say so?

You can use なら with a noun, in which case なら is clearly tense-less:

- iPhoneならできるようになります。
  It will be possible with an iPhone.
- iPhoneならできます。
  It's possible with an iPhone.
- iPhoneならできた。
  I was able to do it with an iPhone. / I managed to do it with an iPhone. (factual)
  I could have done it with an iPhone. (counterfactual)